# how do i select specific words with vowels from a textfile?

Tags: python, text-files

```
# Beginning project
import random

while True:
    g = random.randrange(0,1042)#verbs
    h = random.randrange(0,1435)#noun
    i = random.randrange(0,912) #adjective
    j = random.randrange(0,3)   #person
    k = random.randrange(0,2)   #what
    with open("verbs.txt","r") as z:
        verb = [x.strip().split(" ") for x in z.readlines()]
    with open("nouns.txt","r") as v:
        noun = [x.strip().split(" ") for x in v.readlines()]
    with open("adjectives.txt","r") as a:
        adject = [x.strip().split(" ") for x in a.readlines()]
    with open("person.txt","r") as b:
        who = [x.strip().split(" ") for x in b.readlines()]
    with open("what.txt","r") as c:
        what = [x.strip().split(" ") for x in c.readlines()]
file = open("written.txt","a")

output = (who[j] + verb[g] + what[k] + adject[i] + noun[h])
print(output)
file.write(str(output) + "\n")
```

Thats my code so far.
I have 6 textfiles each have seperate types of words
Eg verbs, adjectives, nouns, who and what and the last one named written is where it outputs to.

I want to do something like this:
If vowel found in noun then use an 
Or if vowel not found in noun then use a

But in code
In python 2.7.12

Comment: you can use https://spacy.io/ (Spacy)?

Comment: So when do you exit from your `while` loop?

Comment: @Iron Fist i dont its meant to generate into a file called written.txt only

Comment: But `while True` has no `break` expression to exit it, it will run forever?

Comment: Yes exactly no break only ctrl c

Comment: apologies for the terrible question, i was young and a terrible coder...lmfao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below logic to do so, if you don't want to use spacy.io.

```
nouns = ['ddd', 'ing', 'king']

for noun in nouns:
    output = 'so so'
    if any([letter in noun for letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']]):
        output += ' an ' + noun
    else:
        output += ' a ' + noun
    print output
```

But, I am guessing, you might want to put **an** if the noun **starts with** vowel instead of **in**. If that is the case you can use the below code

```
for noun in nouns:
    output = 'so so'
    if any([noun.startswith(letter) for letter in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']]):
        output += ' an ' + noun
    else:
        output += ' a ' + noun
    print output
```